Rig Shoulder Cape
Trying to rig a shoulder cape, how can I do this? I'd rather use a skeleton/bone rig.


Hello have you considered using cloth simulation?

I,m trying to make some similar stuff creating bones in the character armature. When yo create your new bones you can later delete the influence of them in the armature, removing some vertex groups, and you should do the same thing for the body bones influences on the cape. I rather recomend to make some FK deformation bones for the cape, and then duplicate and deselect the deformation option to prepare and IK system. If you don,t now about this cuestions i recomend you this videotutorial. enter link description here

I do not know how to use cloth simulation. Can you pose the simulation for a single shot render? I'll gladly take a few tips.

Create your cape, parent it to the top spine bone (select the cape, shift select the armature, switch it to Pose mode, select the bone, and CtrlP Set Parent To > Bone):

Select the cape, switch it to Edit mode, select the top edge loop and CtrlG to assign it to a new vertex group:

Give a Cloth physics to the cape, choose the vertex group you've just created as Pin Group, enable Self Collisions:

Give Collision physics to the body, animate:

